# Udacity: Quiz: Navigating the Food Chain - ternary operator within ternary operator

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working through an Udacity course on Javascript which I got back into after a year. I'm back at a bit that I know answer to but I can't seem to backward engineer it into a simple `if` statement

**Directions:**

Write a series of ternary statements that sets the variable category equal to:

"herbivore" if an animal eats plants
"carnivore" if an animal eats animals
"omnivore" if an animal eats plants and animals
undefined if an animal doesn't eat plants or animals

Use the `eatsPlants` and `eatsAnimals` variables to test your code.

**Working Answer:**

```
var eatsPlants = false;
var eatsAnimals = true;

var category = (eatsPlants) ? (eatsAnimals) ? "omnivore" : "herbivore" 
: (eatsAnimals) ? "carnivore" : undefined;

console.log(category);
```

I'm trying to understand why is there (eatsPlants) ? (eatsAnimals) ?
and why (eatsAnimals) is used twice? or in simple words can someone break this down for me? I'm still very new to coding.

Best I could come up with was this but it didn't help me understand the Ternary version:

```
var eatsPlants = false;
var eatsAnimals = true;

var category;

 if (eatsPlants && eatsAnimals)
 {
    category = "Omnivore"; 

 }  else if (eatsAnimals){
     category="Carnivore"

 } else if (eatsPlants) {
     category = "Herbivore";
 }
 else
 {
     category= undefined;
 }

 console.log(category);
```

Thank you in advance for all the help

Answer (score 0):

It's a confusing piece of code. Indented more logically, it looks like:

```
var category = (eatsPlants)
  ? (eatsAnimals ? "omnivore" : "herbivore")
  : (eatsAnimals ? "carnivore" : undefined);
```

If `eatsPlants` is true, it needs to decide between "omnivore" and "herbivore", based on the `eatsAnimals` condition. Otherwise, if `eatsPlants` is false, it needs to decide between "carnivore" and `undefined` - again, based on the `eatsAnimals` condition.

So, each possible path from `eatsPlants` needs to check the `eatsAnimals` condition in order to determine which string to resolve to.

The `if/else` version would look something like:

```
var category;
if (eatsPlants) {
  if (eatsAnimals) {
    category = 'omnivore';
  } else {
    category = 'herbivore';
  }
} else {
  // eatsPlants is false:
  if (eatsAnimals) {
    category = 'carnivore';
  } else {
    category = undefined;
  }
}
```

As you can see, by using the same logic as the ternary operator version, it has to check `eatsAnimals` twice as well.

I wouldn't recommend using the ternary operator here - the course's question is asking you to write code that looks very confusing. It's not a technique to memorize; I'd prefer using an array instead, so code readers can see the grid:

```js
const categories = [
  // eatsAnimals is
  //   0            1
  [undefined, 'Carnivore'],   // eatsPlants is 0
  ['Herbivore', 'Omnivore']   // eatsPlants is 1
]

var eatsPlants = 0;
var eatsAnimals = 1;
console.log(categories[eatsPlants][eatsAnimals]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't get discouraged and keep on learning to code.
Stuff like this, especially with the way it's formatted, is confusing to **everyone**:

```
var category = (eatsPlants) ? (eatsAnimals) ? "omnivore" : "herbivore" 
: (eatsAnimals) ? "carnivore" : undefined;
```

When looking at this long and complicated combination of ternary statements **always keep the basic syntax of the ternary statement in mind**:

```
(condition) ? expression if true : expression if false
```

I've reformatted the code and added comments to make it easier to read:

```
var category =
    (eatsPlants) ?
    (eatsAnimals) ?   // eatsPlants  === true
    "omnivore" :      // eatsPlants  === true  && eatsAnimals === true
    "herbivore" :     // eatsPlants  === true  && eatsAnimals === false
    (eatsAnimals) ?   // eatsPlants  === false
    "carnivore" :     // eatsAnimals === true
    undefined;        // eatsPlants  === false && eatsAnimals === false
```

If we rewrite the logic using separate if-statements for clarity we get the following:

```
if (eatsPlants === true && eatsAnimals === true) {
    category = 'omnivore';
}
if (eatsPlants === true && eatsAnimals === false)
    category = 'herbivore';
}
if (eatsPlants === false && eatsAnimals === true)
    category = 'carnivore';
}
if (eatsPlants === false && eatsAnimals === false)
    category = 'undefined';
}
```